Extending Laravel Nova: Building a Full Marketplace with Admin and Client Features
I've been diving into Laravel Nova and am really impressed with its intuitive UI and powerful features. As someone still in the learning phase of Laravel, I could really use some guidance from the more experienced developers here.
I'm currently working on a project where I want to extend Laravel Nova beyond its typical use as an admin dashboard. My goal is to build a full marketplace with the following features:

Admin Management:


Creation and management of client accounts.
CRUD operations for all products.


Client Features:


Ability to order products by adding them into a Nova Resource Cart.
Receive discounts based on their orders.
View their complete order history.

I have started setting up the basic admin functionalities using Laravel Nova. The admin can already manage client accounts and perform CRUD operations on products. However, I'm not sure how to extend Nova to handle client-side features like a shopping cart, order history, and applying discounts.
I expected to find some built-in support or packages that could simplify this process, but I haven't found much relevant information. I'm hoping for advice on how to implement these client-side features within Nova or if there are any recommended packages or custom solutions.

Hi, welcome. This question is too broad, and a part is off-topic here on Stack OVerflow.  Please read how to ask to get some help

Hi glad to see a dev exploring Laravel - Your question is too broad as @pierpy says. I suggest watching some tutorials and explore it yourself - open to answers if you run into some specific issues while working with nova. I think you'll be able to find everything here

Thank you for the feedback guys, about my question being too broad. Let me clarify my specific needs.
I am a Laracasts member and have seen the Laravel Nova Mastery series. I know that creating a Policy can solve the authorization issues between Admin and Client for CRUD and view permissions.
My Specific Question:
Can I add an "Add to Cart" button to each product in my Nova Resource Product, so that products can be added to a Nova Resource Cart and then be ordered (tracked in the system for Cash On Delivery - COD, not via Stripe or PayPal)?
